# graph call behind get-cscallqueue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

Is there a Graph equivalent of the `Get-CsCallQueue` command? I tried to search the Teams and Skype Graph documentation, but didn't find it. Tried to check on the GitHub page, but I only found the documentation, not the source code (I am not really familiar with GitHub).

Comment: Using following graph api we can get a log of direct routing calls of Teams
   **GET /communications/callRecords/getDirectRoutingCalls**

Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getdirectroutingcalls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Thanks, yep, been there, but I need the call queues, not the calls themselves. This command lists the Call Queue name, and the corresponding Office group / DL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no graph API available which is equivalent of the Get-CsCallQueue command.

Could you please raise an user voice here:
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new